# Enumerable and Enumerator

Tags: c#

Enumerable support foreach and enumerator support movenext, current and reset but this question is having single correct answer what will be the answer I am not getting. [image]

Comment: The only property on `IEnumerator` is `Current`.  The other member is the `MoveNext` method.  A quick look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator(v=vs.110).aspx) would have answered this for you.

Comment: Thanks juharr, In future I will refer documentation also.

Answer (score 1):

Answers a, b, and c are wrong because the IEnumerator interface doesn't contain any of them.

Answer d is wrong because the question asks which *property* you need to declare, and `Reset` is a method, not a property.